# Корректное подключение галереи на fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, fancybox

Подскажите пожалуйста.

На странице уже подключено несколько слайдеров через разные id. Пытаюсь на ней же сделать галерею через bootstrap + fancybox. К сожалению, галерея выводится просто как миниатюры изображений и по клику на них открывает новое окно с этим же изображением. Нужно сделать так чтобы изображение всплывало в окне и листалось. Может быть будут у кого идеи?

Вот как галерея выглядит в HTML-разметке.  Делать пытался через этот гайд:

https://itchief.ru/lessons/bootstrap-3/bootstrap-3-create-image-galleries

```
<div class="container"> 



  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 thumb">

  <a class="fancyimage" data-fancybox-group="group" href="image1.png"> 
  <img class="img-responsive" src="image1.png" /> 
</a> 

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 thumb">

  <a class="fancyimage" data-fancybox-group="group" href="image1.png"> 
  <img class="img-responsive" src="image1.png" /> 
</a> 

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 thumb">

  <a class="fancyimage" data-fancybox-group="group" href="image1.png"> 
  <img class="img-responsive" src="image1.png" /> 
</a>  

  </div>
```

Comment: с вашей разметкой - все работает - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/qdt49fuc/